# how to remove person or add custom icon in react-native-paper-dates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

**How to remove that person in right hand side of selectRange icon in datepickermodel**

```
          <DatePickerModal
            locale="en"
            mode="range"
            visible={open}
            onDismiss={onDismiss}
            onConfirm={onConfirm}
            closeIcon={customCloseIcon}
            calendarIcon={'none'}
          />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom icon using `editIcon` prop on `DatePickerModal`
you can pass icon from [MaterialCommunityIcons](https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/)

```
 <DatePickerModal
            locale="en"
            mode="range"
            visible={open}
            onDismiss={onDismiss}
            onConfirm={onConfirm}
            closeIcon={customCloseIcon}
            calendarIcon={'none'}
            editIcon={mdiClockEditOutline}    //here
          />
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but this did not change anything. is there any other way I can remove or edit that person's icon?